# UserDefaults not loading first time

Tags: ios, swift, fbsdk, userdefaults

I have a two step login process. On the first screen I save the FB user's details to UserDefaults.

When I load the second ViewController it is supposed to load the user's profile image and username (which I create using "**fullname**"). It actually works the second time I load the user but never the first time, is there some sort of delay? I already tried `UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()` but that does nothing. It even prints the details so I know it works...

```
    let userName = fullName.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_")
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(userName, forKey: "username")

    if let picture = result["picture"] as? NSDictionary , let data = picture["data"] as? NSDictionary, let url = data["url"] as? String {
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(url, forKey: "userFBPicURL")

        let username = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "username") as? String
        let profileImage = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "userFBPicURL") as? String

        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

        print ("Details are User:",username, "profileImage:",profileImage)
```

and in the new VC after `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "UsernameSegue", sender: self)`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let username = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "username") as? String {usernameTextfield.text = username}
    if FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil {loadFacebookProfileImage()}
}
```

Comment: Where have you placed the code you have added in the first snippet?

Comment: In this situation it's not recommended to (mis)use `UserDefaults` as temporary storage for passing data between controllers. Store the data in `UserDefaults` but pass it in `performSegue` to the second controller, this is more reliable. And as always, **never** use `value(forKey` with `UserDefaults`, the proper method is `object(forKey` or in this case even `string(forKey`. The setter is `set(...` **not** `setValue(...`. And don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift, use native types.

Comment: @hardikparmar in my signup method

Comment: Maybe because you `synchronize` it only if you get the picture, data and url. try to `synchronize` it just after you set the user name.

Comment: @hardikparmar that didn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are setting the value to UserDefaults **after** performing segue or **after** the viewDidLoad gets called.

Steps to try find the issue:

1. Could you please try set breakpoint and see what goes first and what second?
2. Try printing from `defaults` right after you assign there.
3. Just try getting data not in ViewDidLoad but later. For example on button tap. Just to see if it's there for the 1st time too (but not only for the 2nd)

Question: where do you set the value to defaults?

PS: Also I wouldn't use UserDefaults for that, but yeah it's a different question.

Sorry, that can't provide an exact solution since it requires more info/code from your debugging. Please try the options above. Hope it helps.

Comment: wow the breakpoints actually pointed out that it is calling the segue before saving the data (which is crazy and makes no sense to me), at least now know where to look for the problem.

Turns out I was calling the segue too early, missed a curly brace after FBAuth...

Comment: @Brewski oh that's good! glad you found it:) I always try using breakpoints for such kind of "timing" issues to see what's wrong. good luck!